# Improve SQLite performance of sql3_step

Tags: performance, sqlite, database-performance, r-tree

I've two tables created in SQLite3 as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "elements" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "instancePointer" INTEGER,
  "layerPointer" INTEGER,
  "clear" BOOLEAN,
  "component" TEXT,
  "pin" TEXT,
  "net" TEXT,
  "apertureCode" INTEGER
)
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE bb USING rtree(id,minX,maxX,minY,maxY)
```

In my current test setup I run the following query about 12150 times, resulting in about 102806 rows to be returned in total, which takes 90 seconds:

```
SELECT elements.instancePointer
FROM elements, bb
WHERE 
    (elements.layerPointer=? OR elements.layerPointer=? OR ...)
    AND elements.id=bb.id 
    AND maxX>=:rectMinX
    AND minX<=:rectMaxX
    AND maxY>=:rectMinY
    AND minY<=:rectMaxY
ORDER BY layerPointer, elements.id DESC
```

The `elements.layerPointer` in the WHERE clause is repeated a number of times, with different values of course.

I basically query the RTree table and also require the `layerPointer` property to have a certain list of values.

I do use the `lastInsertedRowId` function of SQLite, so I need the row id column other than to link the `elements` and `bb` tables.

Executing a `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` comes up with the following information:

```
EXPLAIN: <Row id:4 parent:0 notused:0 detail:"SCAN TABLE bb VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 2:D1B0D3B2">
EXPLAIN: <Row id:12 parent:0 notused:0 detail:"SEARCH TABLE elements USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)">
EXPLAIN: <Row id:23 parent:0 notused:0 detail:"USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY">
```

Adding an index to the `layerPointer` column causes the RTree to be `SCAN`'ed without a special index, resulting in an even increased execution time.

Profiling shows that all time is spend in `sqlite3_step()`. Is there a way to increase the performance of this query? Maybe by adding an index that is just used for the `ORDER BY` part (if that's the bottleneck)?

Comment: Most probably that won't change anything, but: `(elements.layerPointer=? OR elements.layerPointer=? OR ...)` can be simplified to `elements.layerPointer in (?,?,...)`

Comment: Sqlite 3.24 lets you keep extra non-coordinate columns in a rtree table, avoiding the need for joins. That might help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that at least looks better.

Comment: @Shawn unfortunately I’m stuck with an older version at the moment, but I’ll investigate it for the future.